# Browsing local directories and files with php

Tags: php

Instead of the traditional navigation, I am trying to emulate the terminal navigation, or how you navigate with vim.
Example:

```
..
index
otherfile
```

This is my code:

```
$dir = realpath(dirname(__FILE__));
if(is_dir($dir)){
    if($open = opendir($dir)){
        while(($file = readdir($open)) !==false){
        if(is_dir($file)){
             if($file == '.'){ }
             else{
                echo "<a href=".$file.">".$file."</a><br/>";
            }
        } 
        else{       
        $name = explode('.php',$file);
        echo "<a href=".$file.">".$name[0]."</a><br/>";
        }
        }

    }
}
else{
    echo $dir." Was not found";
    }
 }
```

1. How can I remove the file or folder I am in from the list? For example, if I am on the page index.php, it is still appearing on the list.
2. I want to sort files by given them a number example '1file.php' '2anotherfile.php'..
   How could I sort them by the number, then remove the number and '.php', and finally print it out?

If you feel like refactoring something please do so...

[image]

Comment: Can you add the example output you're looking for to your question, it's not very clear.

Comment: Yea, check the top of the question under, where it says example...

Comment: I think you could have done that using PHP's DirectoryIterator, check some examples: http://www.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.next.php

Comment: Also, what's are you trying to do with the number you want to prefix the files with?

Comment: Filtering the files in the order I want, I could add a number to specify the order of the files. How could I do it with DirectoryIterator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. *"How can I remove the file or folder I am in from the list? For example, if I am on the page index.php, it is still appearing on the list."*

Just check if the current item is the current file, if it is then skip it:

```
else {
    if ($name == basename(dirname(__FILE__))) continue; // if this is the current file, go to the next iteration of the loop
    $name = explode('.php',$file);
    echo "<a href=".$file.">".$name[0]."</a><br/>";
}
```

Note that this assumes you are in the same directory as the file (which it can do because `$dir` is always the directory the script is in), if not you can just add a directory check as well.

1. *"How can add a number to the start of the file or folder, example 1index.php, then on the code, organize all the files and folder by number, and print them without the number and '.php'?"*

Well I'm not too sure what you mean by this, but if you mean sort alphabetically, then it is already alphabetically sorted when you get the list.